# Solidity Bytes Comparison

Tags: solidity, bytes

I was going through the [Create Your Own CryptoCurrency](https://www.ethereum.org/token) documentation and got stuck at the **proofOfWork** section. In this, they try to do a check i.e.

`require(n >= bytes(difficulty)) //Check if its under difficulty`

I wanted to understand, what kind of comparison is being done here?

1. Is is byte-to-byte comparison?
2. Is there some conversion happening before the check?
3. Or, its just a length check (which I think isn't the case, but just to be sure, I added it here).

If someone can point me to the right resource on the same.

Comment: The current code in the linked page reads `require(n >= bytes8(difficulty))`. `bytes8` is a fixed-length array of bytes that defines `>=`, among other comparators. I assume it's doing a byte-to-byte comparison. The code you shared shouldn't compile.

Comment: Hmm. If you can provide any reference for this assumption. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see the implementation details anywhere. My assumption is just based on the fact that otherwise such a comparison wouldn't make sense. Compiling the code and looking at the assembly might be a good way to verify if we're unable to find documentation.

Comment: Yeah. Even I didn’t find any docs on this. Oh ok. Will try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

if n is greater then or equals to the number of bytes in the difficulty then it will be TRUE statement.

Bytes function in python explained:

```
Return a new “bytes” object, which is an immutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256. bytes
```

ex:

```
var n = 16
var difficulty = 0x10

var bytes = bytes(difficulty) // 16
n >= bytes is true
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're basing this answer on. Could you provide some evidence for your claim?